# CDbCommand failed error in MySQL after insert

Tags: mysql, database, yii, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have a MySQL database for Group and Member.When I am going to insert any record in Group model, everything is fine here but when I am going to insert any data in Member model it is showing error like this

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tbl_groupapp`.`tbl_member`, CONSTRAINT `FK_member_group` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_member` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`, `membersince`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3)
```

I don't know why it is happening here.Here is my database schema

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_group`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_group`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_group` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(37, 'Test Group'),
(38, 'bdbsdsb'),
(39, 'ruieryei'),
(40, 'dbshdbs'),
(41, 'dbshdbs'),
(42, 'dbshdbs'),
(43, 'dbshdbs'),
(44, 'dbshdbs'),
(45, 'dbshdbs'),
(46, 'dbshdbs'),
(47, 'dbshdbs'),
(48, 'dbshdbs'),
(49, 'dbshdbs'),
(50, 'group name'),
(51, 'group name'),
(52, 'dbshdbs');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_member`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `membersince` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_member_group` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=52 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_member`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_member` (`id`, `group_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`, `membersince`) VALUES
(31, 37, 'First Name', 'Second Name', 'male', '2012-02-22 00:00:00'),
(32, 38, 'dsadsmadnas', 'jieo/uwoe', 'female', '2012-02-16 00:00:00'),
(33, 39, 'rerhejrgejh', 'nmbfdnfb,d', 'male', '2012-02-23 00:00:00'),
(34, 40, 'test group', 'test group', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(35, 41, 'test group1', 'test group2', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(36, 42, 'test group1', 'test group2', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(37, 43, 'test group', 'test group2', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(38, 44, 'test group1', 'test group2', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(39, 45, 'test group', 'test group2', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(40, 46, 'test group', 'test group2', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(41, 47, 'test group1', 'test group2', 'male', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(42, 48, 'test group1', 'test group2', 'm', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(43, 49, 'test group1', 'test group2', 'Male', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(44, 50, 'firstname ', 'secondname', 'Male', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(45, 51, 'test group', 'test group', 'Male', '2012-02-28 00:00:00'),
(46, 52, 'test group', 'test group2', 'Male', '2012-02-15 00:00:00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Constraints for table `tbl_member`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_member`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_member_group` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.
Here is the form file for Member

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'member-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

  <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

  <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'group_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'group_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'group_id'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstname'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>80)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstname'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lastname'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>80)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'lastname'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gender'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'gender',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'gender'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'membersince'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'membersince'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'membersince'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
  </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Controllere Code For Member

```
<?php

class MemberController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
   * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
   */
  public $layout='//layouts/column2';

  /**
   * @return array action filters
   */
  public function filters()
  {
    return array(
      'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
  }

  /**
   * Specifies the access control rules.
   * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
   * @return array access control rules
   */
  public function accessRules()
  {
    return array(
      array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
        'actions'=>array('index','view'),
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
        'actions'=>array('create','update'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
        'users'=>array('admin'),
      ),
      array('deny',  // deny all users
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Displays a particular model.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
   */
  public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new model.
   * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   */
  public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Member;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Member']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Member'];
      if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Updates a particular model.
   * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
   */
  public function actionUpdate($id)
  {
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Member']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Member'];
      if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Deletes a particular model.
   * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
   */
  public function actionDelete($id)
  {
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
      // we only allow deletion via POST request
      $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

      // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
      if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
      throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
  }

  /**
   * Lists all models.
   */
  public function actionIndex()
  {
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Member');
    $this->render('index',array(
      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Manages all models.
   */
  public function actionAdmin()
  {
    $model=new Member('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Member']))
      $model->attributes=$_GET['Member'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
   * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
   * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
   */
  public function loadModel($id)
  {
    $model=Member::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
      throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
  }

  /**
   * Performs the AJAX validation.
   * @param CModel the model to be validated
   */
  protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
  {
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='member-form')
    {
      echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
      Yii::app()->end();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your schema is fine, you are trying to insert from a form right? If so see my answer below, lemme know if you need help with the form.

Comment: I have already given group_id in my form but still the error is comming.I have updated my question with form file.

Comment: ok, that form looks fine. the controller please then.

Comment: ok.controller looks fine too. then while testing it, did you set/enter the correct group_id, in the text field?

Comment: Ok..here I was wrong.I was giving random id for that.Thats why I was getting error.Can you tell me how to solve that,so that I can save the form without any id placed in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have missed inserting the foreign key **group id** into the table which is seen from error you are getting, as in, this:

> The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_member` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`, `membersince`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3)

Basically you have to insert the group_id also, so add group_id input field also to your form for member model.

Lemme know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have used Yii multimodel and I have called Member in Group's controller and I can save both model there.But in Member model it is showing error. So I think again I have to call Group model inside it I think

Comment: if you can share your controller code, and the form code for member, we can pin point the missing code exactly. So put up the code if you wish.

Comment: ok..just try this before anything else, echo $form->dropDownList($model,'group_id',CHtml::listData(Group::model()->findAll(),'id','name'));

Comment: put that dropdownlist instead of the textfield you have for group_id in the form

Comment: ok..from your comment in the question..are you sure you want to remove the id from the form?, or do you want to give the user an option to select the group?

Comment: I want to remove the id. I want simply the user will fill the form without any id to submit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7471/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-newuser)

Comment: ok, for that you have to remove the entire group_id input field from the form, remove `<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'group_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'group_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'group_id'); ?>
  </div>`